# count columns containing value pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have combination of `true/false/null` data in one column. I wish to count number of `false`, number of `true` but don't want it to be `0` if only null's are in the column.

Example 1.csv:

```
column
null
null
```

The count for `true` and `false` must be `None`.

Example 2.csv:

```
column
null
null
true
true
true
false
false
true
```

`true` count should be `4`, `false` count should be `2`.

Example 3.csv:

```
column
null
null
true
true
true
true
```

`true` count should be `4`, `false` count should be `0`.

Currently counting works, but only in second and thid (2.csv, 3.csv) case:

```
df_o['counta'] = (df_t['column'] == 1).resample(interval).sum().astype(int)
df_o['countb'] = (df_t['column'] == 0).resample(interval).sum().astype(int)
```

Oh and I am using `resample`.

Comment: `df.column.value_counts()`

Comment: That will not give the count of `true` and `false` values for example 1

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df1.column.value_counts().reindex([True,False])
Out[113]: 
True    NaN
False   NaN
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do I store those values to separated column?

Comment: @krizajb using map df1['New']=df1.column.map(df1.column.value_counts().reindex([True,False]))

Comment: Totally confused with this pandas :) Not sure how to use this solution with `resample`. resample then count? Testing ...

Comment: Well basically if both values are 0, they are None. I think this is easier to understand/implement. Let me know what you think.